# Some function of Category collection is not workiing in 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, programmatically

I used Category Collection but is show error in product count is fixed it but after that is show error in Set product is and attribute set.
I am trying this by Problematically.
My code: 
`$storeId = $_SESSION["store_id"] ? $_SESSION["store_id"] : $this->session->userdata('store_id');`

```
public function get_categories() 
{
    $storeId = store_id;
    $web_id = website_id;
    $rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"))
        //->setProductStoreId($storeId)
        ->addFieldToFilter('store_id',$storeId)
        // ->setLoadProductCount(1)
        ->getSize(1)
        // ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        // ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'),'inner')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','url'));

    foreach ($categories as $_category)
    {
        $img = $_category->getImageUrl();
        $data[] = array('category_id' => $_category->getEntityId(), 'category_name' => $_category->getName(), 'image' => $imgUrl);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Now this code is showing `Fatal error: Call to a member function addAttributeToSelect() on a non-object`

Comment: I believe you need to use `setPageSize` instead of `getSize` method.

Answer (score 1):

use bellow code

```
    $storeId = 1;
    $web_id = 1;
    $rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('path')
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"))
            //->setPageSize(1)
            //->setCurPage(1)
            ;

    foreach ($categories as $_category)
    {
        $img = $_category->getImageUrl();
        $data[] = array('category_id' => $_category->getEntityId(), 'category_name' => $_category->getName(), 'image' => $imgUrl);
    }
     print_r($data)
```